# rvm Error running './configure

Tags: macos, ruby, rvm

### Description

After I migrating my Macbook to the new one, I encounter an error during reinstalling `rvm`

### Steps to reproduce

```
⋊> rvm install 2.3.3
```

### Environment

1. OSX 10.13.3
2. rvm version: rvm `1.29.3` (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski
3. system ruby: ruby `2.5.0p0`
4. fish shell, version `2.5.0`

### Expected behavior

Install ruby `2.3.3` via `rvm`  perfectly.

### Actual behavior

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.3.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Coda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.3 - #downloading ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.3 - #extracting ruby-2.3.3 to /Users/Coda/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.3.....
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/Coda/.rvm/patches/ruby/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/Coda/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.3/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #configuring........................
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Coda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.7:/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1:/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.5:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/Coda/.rvm/log/1518890785_ruby-2.3.3/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Log file /Users/Coda/.rvm/log/1518890785_ruby-2.3.3/configure.log contains the following:

```
checking size of long long... configure: error: in `/Users/Coda/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.3':
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long)
See `config.log' for more details
```

Environment info is here
(https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/47bb65311f9c1399f327e2a470251a42)

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue after migrating my Mac too (both MacOS High Sierra). 
After running

```
sudo mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/include_old
```

and then

```
rvm install 2.5.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

things started working normally.

Comment: Just doing the `mv` command worked great for me. Thank you!